# Странный глюк при работе с БД

Tags: php, mysql

Доброй ночи! У меня есть несколько таблиц в БД. Так вот элементарный код:

```
<?php
 $hostname = 'localhost';
 $username = 'root';
 $passwordname = '';
 $basename = 'web';

 $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwordname, $basename) 
 or die ('Невозможно открыть базу');
 $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Редактор статей.</title>
</head>
<body>
        <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM art";
            $result=$conn->query($sql);            
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {

        }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда ставишь значение одной таблицы в запрос SELECT все срабатывает. А когда подставляю имя другой таблицы, то вываливает ошибку: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/u802234239/public_html/example/1.php on line 20`.
Таблицы созданы. Через phpMyAdmin запросы выполняются успешно на первую и вторую таблицу.

Причем проверял это и на локальной машине и на хостинге. Такая же ерунда. В чем может быть причина? Подскажите... Мистика какая-то...

Comment: а как называется другая таблица ? может её имя - ключевое слово mysql ?

Comment: @IntegralAL, может быть другая таблица пуста ?

Comment: Работающая таблица называется goods, а не рабочая art. Обе заполенные. Через phpMyAdmin запросы SELECT выводят данные. А через php Файл ошибку дает с таблицей art. Пробовал обрамлять название таблицы в кавычки тоже не помогло...

Comment: Попробуй удалить код этой странички и написать заново. А ещё попробуй переименовать таблицу, которая ошибку даёт.

Comment: Я пробовал создавать другие таблицы и подлючал их ко коду своему, они тоже не пашут. А переписывать код долго. У меня целый проект написан и он не работает зараза. А завтра сдавать надо его. А то что я тут выложил это просто простейший вариант который также глючит, как и все остальное...

Comment: @IntegralAL, для того, чтоб не приходилось переписывать тонны кода, повторяющиеся его участки (*а подключение к БД, запросы - это и есть одними из таких*), надо оформлять в классы или функции. В вашем случае, как говориться, найдите "десять отличий", т.е. определите где была ошибка и замените её, где она ещё присутствует. Многие редакторы позволяют менять код документа по регулярному выражению. Это может ускорить вашу рутину в десятки раз.

Comment: У меня так и сделано. Одна точка входа, набор функций. Это я тут для примера просто привел подключение и обращение к базе. Вообще файл с функциями и подключением к базе очень большой. Переписывать его долго. Потому должно быть решение какое-то другое. Пока я подключил к старой таблице для демо-показа, а дальше конечно эту проблему надо как-то решать...

Comment: @IntegralAL, ну ошибка же у вас не начинается в начале страницы и не заканчивается в её конце! Ошибка где-то в одном месте и где-то в районе работы с БД. Вот и сравните эту часть кода в старом варианте и новом, который заработал.

P.S. Обрамляйте названия таблиц и полей в обратные одинарные кавычки. Если что, то это там, где русская буква **Ё**.

Comment: вообще необходимо заключать таблицы в кавычки, например: `table_name`

 и использовать PDO

Comment: Если запрос нормально обрабатывается в например, phpmyadmin, то попробуйте, пожалуйста, установить кодировку следуюшим способом $conn->set_charset("utf8"), если не поможет, то для проверки попробовать закомментировать на время эту строку.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `art`";
if ($result=$conn->query($sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {

    }
}
else {
    echo "что-то не так.";
}
```

А вообще, тот же запрос скопируй в PhpMyAdmin и выполни его там. Может он тебе что подскажет.